# res.should.have.status gives me error

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, should.js

I'm new to mocha and should.js. I'm trying to check the response's status but it gives me `TypeError: Object #<Assertion> has no method 'status'` The code is like this:

```
describe('Local signup', function() {
    it('should return error trying to save duplicate username', function(done) {
      var profile = {
        email: 'abcd@abcd.com',
        password: 'Testing1234',
        confirmPassword: 'Testing1234',
        firstName: 'Abc',
        lastName: 'Defg'
      };
      request(url)
          .post('/user/signup')
          .send(profile)
          .end(function(err, res) {
            if (err) {
              throw err;
            }
            res.should.have.status(400);
            done();
          });
    });
```

I also noticed that although I have declared `var should = require('should');` , my ide notifies me that 'should' is a unused local variable. I don't really know why.

Comment: Are you running this in a browser?

Comment: @plalx Tagged with `node.js`.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko I know, but it says in the docs that `status` is not part of the browser build, so I got suspicious.

Comment: @plalx I run the test in terminal

Comment: `res.should.have.status()` is something which is available **only with some implementation of the `should` idiom**. In other words, the error may happen because the package used to provide `should` does not implement `status`, or because the package has not been correctly initialized, or for some other reason. Nothing in this question indicates what package provides `should`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try

```
res.status.should.be.equal(400);
```

or

```
 res.should.have.property('status', 400);
```

And about " 'should' is a unused local variable". It's true. You don't use should directly. Only sideeffects. Try `require('should');` instead.

Comment: Thanks Yury, it works, but why doesn't 'res.should.have.status(400);' work? I found many examples online, they also use res.should.have.status().

Comment: I believe you need additional package https://www.npmjs.com/package/supertest-chai

Comment: It is not about `chai`.

Answer (score 3):

Place the line:

```
require('should-http');
```

somewhere in your code. E.g.:

```
require('should-http');

describe('Test Something', function() {
    ...
```

Answer (score 2):

As an addition to Yury answer. There is [should-http](https://www.npmjs.com/package/should-http) package, which contain `.status(code)` assertion. You need to require somewhere it in code and it will be added to should.js.

Answer (score 1):

I would switch to `expect`:

```
expect(res.status).to.be.eq(400);
```